How to assign a definition locally?
I want to define a changeable string in latex so that I can modify it each time I want.
Let us call it \xx.
\xx=abc
\xx def gives abc def
\xx=def
\xx def gives def def
How can I make this?

Welcome to TeX.SE.

You've tagged this tex-core, but your question says LaTeX.  Those are two different things.  If you aren't aware of the distinction, go with LaTeX.

Everything inside {} is local (well, it is not fully true, but in your example it is). So for example:
{\def\xx{abc}

\texttt{\string{\xx}} def gives \xx\ def}}

{\def\xx{def}

\texttt{\string{\xx} def gives \xx\ def}}


Something like this?

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\def\xx{abc }
\verb+\xx def+ gives ``\xx def''

%% use "{" and "}" to localize scope of next \def instruction
{
\def\xx{def }
\verb+\xx def+ gives ``\xx def''
}

\verb+\xx def+ gives ``\xx def''

\end{document}


There's no notion of “variable” in TeX. There are registers and macros.
But you can emulate variables.
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % this and twocolumn just for the example

\ExplSyntaxOn

% ‘tv’ is for ‘text variable’
\NewDocumentCommand{\tvset}{mm}
 {% #1 = var name, #2 = value
  \tl_clear_new:c { l_weixiao_tv_#1_tl }
  \tl_set:cn  { l_weixiao_tv_#1_tl } {#2}
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\tvuse}{m}
 {% #1 = var name
  \tl_use:c  { l_weixiao_tv_#1_tl }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\tvset{xx}{abc}

\tvuse{xx} def gives `abc def'

\begin{center}
\tvset{xx}{def}%
\tvuse{xx} def gives `def def'
\end{center}

\tvuse{xx} def gives `abc def'

\end{document}

Environments in LaTeX form a scope, so the value of xx will be restored as soon as \end{center} is executed.

Note. Other answers suggest \def. I disagree: exposing \def to a beginner is very dangerous for their health. Next thing they'll do is \def\box{abc} or similar Armageddon-like error.

Nice note, ehem, warning …

+1 for "exposing a beginner to \def is very dangerous for their health." :-)

@Mico This user will not be worried. He will Laugh. ;-)

Your suggested syntax isn't TeX native syntax. You can use \xx as a macro:
\def\xx{abc}
\xx\ def gives abc def

i.e. the setting a new value is done using \def and using the value simply by writing the control sequence of the macro (followed by \  here because you want to print space after abc).
Or you can use \xx as a token register:
\newtoks\xx

\xx={abc}
\the\xx\ def gives abc def

I.e. the setting a new value is similar to your syntax. Only difference is that you have to tell TeX where the value begins and where it ends by {...}. Using the value is now done by prefixing \the TeX primitive, i.e. it is not exactly your suggested syntax. Typically, you can select first or second possibility shown here, if you don't insist your syntax.
Your example has nothing to do with settings the values locally (you mention it in your title but it isn't shown it in your example). Of course, setting a new value overwrites the previous one in both my examples shown above. And the setting the value is local inside TeX groups given by { and } or by \beingroup, \endgroup. Also both examples. If you want global setting, use \gdef in the first example or \global\xx= in the second one.
If you insist on your syntax then you have to specify, where the end of the given value is (which is not clear in your syntax). Maybe, it is the first space. Then you can create a macro \xx which uses \futurelet TeX primitive to distinguish whether it is setting or using the value (by following = or not). And the value itself is saved in the \xxC internal macro.
\def\xx{\futurelet\next\xxA}
\def\xxA{\ifx\next=\expandafter\xxB \else \xxC \fi}
\def\xxB=#1 {\def\xxC{#1 }}

\xx=abc

\xx def gives abc def

\xx=def

\xx def gives def def

\bye

